# Adal Angular4 - AcquireToken call is returning 'Token renewal operation failed due to timeout error'

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I'm trying to call Microsoft Graph Api from the adal-angular4 sample project [adal-angular4-example](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4-example).

I have added this code to get the token for the graph api.

**home.component.ts**

```
getGraphToken(){

    if (this.service.getCachedToken([** CLIENT-ID **])){

      //this.service.handleWindowCallback();

      this.service.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com")
        .subscribe(
          data => console.log(data), 
          err => console.log(err));
    }

    //this.service.handleWindowCallback();

  }
```

**home.component.html**

```
  <tr>
    <span><button md-button (click)="getGraphToken();">Get Graph Token</button></span>
  </tr>
```

**updated app.component.ts with the azure config**

```
// Adal Configuration
const config = {
  tenant: 'tenant-id-here',
  clientId: 'client-id-here'
};
```

For some reason I am getting the error 'Token renewal operation failed due to timeout' instead of the data token being populated.

If I look in the network tab of the browser, I can see the response has a 302 and does have the new access token attached.

I can manually copy this access token, go to postman, add it as a bearer token, and make successful calls against the graph.

It just appears that the handling of the callback is not being handled to actually bring it in.

I've also tried it with various locations of the handleWindowCallback function.

Any ideas for how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

When you acquireToken then the page should not refresh before it call **handleWindowCallback**.

After logged In where you're redirecting get the handleWindowCallback over there and then get data using acquireToken will return the data.

```
return this.adalService.acquireToken(environment.config.spUrl).flatMap(
      token => {
        const headersParam = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.toString()
        });
        return this.http.get(url, { headers: headersParam });
      });
```